# Ubuntu 14.04 get back "old" wireless driver from 13

Tags: wireless

I just updated to 14.04 and I am loving it. The only problem is, that I used to be able to connect to my company's WiFi on 13.10 but since I updated it's not possible any more.

Many distros have problems with that network but, however, 13.10 could connect.

I can connect to "normal" networks on 14.04 without problems, but this network is a bit picky so my question now is, **how can I roll back to the driver / network manager from 13.10?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It was an annoying bug in the network manager.

opening a the config file for this specific network via

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETWORK_NAME
```

Made me realise that `system-ca-certs` has automatically been set to `true` although the network doesn't provide any certificate. Setting it back to `false` makes the connection work again.

[bug report regarding this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1104476)